# New internal user add to Office 365 considered as an External user

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Recently we added a new team member to our organisation with our domain name (@ourcompanyname), I gave him Office 365 E3 licence, when i try to add him to a SharePoint group in a random site, it tells me that i can't add him until i change my external sharing policy (which is Only members in organisation).

I can't understand what's happening ! The user is in my organisation !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue in my environment.

The new user is identified as an external user because it hasn’t been added to the tenant’s directory (although it has been listed in the Azure Active Directory).

I’m afraid there is not much we can do until SharePoint adds this user to **User profiles** in SharePoint admin center (`_layouts/15/tenantprofileadmin/ProfMngr.aspx`), since the user profiles are managed and synced by SharePoint itself.

Until then the user won’t be accepted as an internal user.

Another similar post for your reference:
[Internal User can't be found in directory error when accessing Sharepoint.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/internal-user-cant-be-found-in-directory-error/8b2e2f46-f1f7-4725-80b2-9678171c155a)

---

UPDATE: The users I created for testing have been added to the directory after 24 hours.

Comment: Yes indeed, the same happens to me